# Woocommerce hardcoded Facebook like button shows up twice

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We wanted to add multiple product sizes for one or more items on our site, running on woocommerce plugins.

There is a facebook like button that shows up below the Add to Cart button once a product size has been selected.

On every page the Facebook like button shows up fine, except for those products for which you can select multiple sizes. Then the like button shows up twice.

I didn't build the site, but found the hardcoded section for the FB-like button in the functions.php file. I included it here. Is it perhaps missing some bit of code to keep from duplicating in said instances?

Here's the page on the site: http://www.hottot.com/shop/shampoo/

Here's the code at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/MYh0SHWG

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is a script you guys are using is already adding a facebook button

```
 function nme_wc_after_add_to_cart_button() {
        echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d . getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d . createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs . parentNode . insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }

        (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));</script>

    <div class="fb-like" style="float:left; margin-top:12px;" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/HotTotHaircare" data-send="false" data-width="250" data-show-faces="true"></div>';
```

first you echo echo `'<div id="fb-root"></div>` next you add

```
<div class="fb-like" style="float:left; margin-top:12px;" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/HotTotHaircare" data-send="false" data-width="250" data-show-faces="true"></div>';
```

so 2 i think your generating 2x a button

Comment: So you're saying to remove the script? Tried it, but that makes the like button not show on any pages, except, weirdly, it still shows twice only on those product pages with two different sizes of product. Facebook's instructions are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ Their recommendation is how the code is set up currently for XFBML.

Comment: really strange cant find the problem